# Why does the ScrollBar moves when I delete an ItemsSource element?

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, itemssource

I have a grid which ItemsSource is bound to a list of string. When I remove an element from the ItemsSource, the ScrollBar moves to the removed element, which is problematic for me.

For example, my grid contains 100 rows. The user is focusing the 100th row. The user gives the order to remove the first row: the ScrollBar moves to the second row.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Show us your code please. We would like to see how have you set the preferences to your grid. Futhermore tell us are you resetting the value of ItemsSource when you change something in your list? Are you using ObservableCollection?

Anyways take a look at this propertly. Maybe this is what you looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
<ListBox Name="employeeListBox1"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Employees}}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmployeeItemTemplate}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
```

IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem should prevent scrollbars to be moved without your permissions. :)

Comment: When I add or remove an element in the itemsSource, I don't reset it, I use the Add() / AddRange() and Remove() / RemoveRange() methods. My ItemsSource is not an ObservableCollection, but this doesn't prevent the interface to be updated. Unfortunately, the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: You should make your list an ObservableCollection.

Comment: Yes I should... I thought it was but I just realized after you asked it that it is not. Could this be the source of my issue?

Comment: Not sure since you havent posted us code of exactly what you up to. I dont know what you up to. We must see xaml and code behind and viewmodel to understand your issue. I dont know why you not using ObservableCollection. Is there a reason why you decided to use List? I can just keep guessing cases which usually appear. :) Try it with ObservableCollection.

Comment: Actually, the reason I'm not using an ObservableCollection is because this List of string is built in a WCF service, and retrieved from the WPF interface. What would be the best solution: convert it from List to ObservableCollection in my interface, or define it as an ObservableCollection in the service (not really possible I guess)?

Comment: You can pass list to ObservableVollection constructor. Take a look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: Yes, thank you :) Anyway, converting my ItemsSource from a List to an ObservableCollection didn't solve my issue.

Comment: How about you give us more code? I will stop guessing what I might be. :) :) :)